# Should we allow a pending edit to be modified then approved?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, I can see that a question or answer can be improved better than I can think of a way to improve it and want to make a pending edit to give an idea of how to improve it but don't have enough knowledge to make the full improvement or the form I edited it to would be worse than the current form but give an idea of how to improve it. If they could be modified then approved, then some pending edits that made a question or answer worse in its current form would be approved and some edits that actually made the question or answer better in its current form would lead to the question or answer being even better.

Comment: I have trouble imagining a suggested edit that would make a post *worse* yet lead to any kind of better result. Can you give a specific example?

Answer (score 3):

That would be pointless.

If you have an idea how to improve a post but not sure how to do that yourself, just add a comment.

This way the post author will see it, and will be able to edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

> Should we allow a pending edit to be modified then approved?

That *is* already how suggested edits work (well, technically they are approved then modified).

When reviewing suggested edits, there is the option to "Improve Edit", which approves the suggestion but allows the reviewer to continue editing and further improve the post.

> [image]

Edits that would in themselves make no improvement or actively harm the post should be avoided though; reviewers aren't obliged to improve your edit and if they do choose to improve an edit that was no improvement in itself then they should "Reject and Edit"; rejecting your edit.

If you have a suggestion to improve a post but cannot write the improvements yourself, you already have a perfect mechanism for suggesting it; comments.

If your edit *does* improve the post but you feel the post could be further improved, by all means suggest an edit. Hopefully the reviewer will improve on your suggestion and you can suggest further improvements in a comment.